# Why does my river change itself into a big, flat (with some bumps) square when i use the ocean modifier?

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation

I already tried to apply the scale, but unfortunately nothing's changed. How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the Ocean modifier is set to generate its own geometry and discard whatever you're applying it on.

To have it use your existing geometry, just *Generate* to *Displace*:

[image: displace ocean]